# Is it bound to answer an implication statement by using 'if p then q' format only?

Tags: logic

Question_" John gets caught whenever he cheats."
Answer_ converse "John cheats whenever he gets caught."
Inverse" John doesn't get caught whenever he doesn't cheat."
Contrapositive "John doesn't cheat whenever he doesn't get caught"

Look, this question is asked in my exam containing 6 marks. I gave the correct answer using "whenever", but my department gave me 0, by saying that answers can't be written by using "whenever". In department's view answer can be only written in "if p then q" format.

Please, tell me "Is it bound to write answers by using only 'if p then q' format ?". Although there are many methods of writing an implication statement.
I just want to know the correct methods of answering, I don't need marks.

Comment: What was your answer? Also, a tad presumptuous to assume it must've been correct

Comment: Also, the title has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: @Vsotvep hey, I just want to know "Do we need to write an implication statement always using 'if p then q' format while answering a question. I think you know that we can write implication statements by using ' if p then q', 'q whenever p', 'q unless negation p' etc.

Comment: None of those is a logical formula. A logical formula would be $p\to q$, $p\implies q$ or $p\supset q$, depending on the author.

Comment: @Vsotvep ok, I edited my post. Now tell me.

Comment: "John gets caught whenever he cheats" is **not a question**. If the question was "give English sentences that have the same meaning as the converse / inverse / contrapositive of this sentence", then you did the job. If the question was "give a logical formula depicting the converse / inverse / contrapositive of this sentence" then you did not, since those are not logical formulas, but sentences in English. And please do not use imperatives to demand an answer, it is rude and does not invite people to help you.

Comment: @Vsotvep I think you have some misunderstanding, I joined this community to get helped. But, still if you have issue ok, I am deleting that comment.

Comment: Your exam question asked to "write the ... of this sentence". As it does not ask you any format, I would personally think you deserve full points, both from the perspective of the answers showing that you understood the meaning of inverse, converse and contrapositive, as well as from the perspective that "write" is a pretty unclear way to ask a question about logic.

Comment: @Vsotvep ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is it bound to write answers by using only 'if p then q' format ?"

It shouldn't be bound on which format we write our answer. These type of answers are usually what we call propositions. But when is something a proposition and when is it not?
A proposition is some statement that we could only classify as being either true or false.

Think of the word "True" being something that it true and "False" of something that is false. These are the two type of blocks we have to create a proposition of itself. As we usually want to create more complex statements we need something to connect/chain propositions together, in most abstract form these come down to some symbols on which either someone else defined what the effect is of connecting propositions and thus the rules for the outcome of the new proposition. Hence, it is possible to have connectives that are for example the same symbol, yet the meaning would not be the same.

One more concrete example: The first counting symbol of a set of number is always 1. Take a mathematician, a programmer, and some person who is not a mathematician nor a programmer. Some people say the statement is true while others say it is false.

In general when we are connecting abstract propositions we use Capital letters to either define a statement for the letter which can only answer True or False. Then we use the following symbol to connect them. Note that not each connective has the same priority when being constructed to our proposition. Hence we make use of the symbols ( and ) to make it clear which order we desire, since depending on the amount of ( and ) we can have different outcomes for each proposition in our complete proposition.
Note we use the letters P and Q to be any proposition, so it can be either true of false being only the letter itself.

> Main connectives
>   1. Negation $\neg P$  - whatever P is true, $\neg P$ is the opposite
>
> 2. Implication $P \neg Q$ - whenever P is true, it follows that Q is also true. (but this proposition is also true when both P and Q are false) One way to remember the meaning is to think of "If P is true, Q can't be false or my statement is valid."
> 3. Bi-Implication $ P \iff Q$ is basicaly the implication in both direction. Thus it means this proposition is only true when the values of P and Q seperate are equal. Sometimes called "if and only if".
> 4. And $P \land Q$ is true only when both P and Q are true, otherwise it is false.
> 5. Or $P \lor Q$ is true when either P or Q is true or when both are true. Sometimes this connective can be defined such that it is false when both are true. But for now we keep it simple.

Now with some abstracts definitions coming back to your question.

> "Is it bound to write answers by using only 'if p then q' format ?"

Lets our answer be using propositions itself. Suppose we have a Proposition which we cal P. It can be either evaluate to True or false. Using P and our connectives we can create an endless amount of propositions which have a concrete amount of outcomes. In other words, we can create propositions which are true, or false but they cant be none of both.

So in other words: we can have multiple answers which are correct for a given context. For this we use truth tables to evaluate what the outcomes are for any input of proposition. Otherwise we could always say that False $=>$ anything, and we would be always right.

You defined the following:

> Let Q be Question_"John gets caught whenever he cheats."
>
> Let A be Answer_ converse "John cheats whenever he gets caught."
>
> Let I Inverse" John doesn't get caught whenever he doesn't cheat."
>
> Let C Contrapositive "John doesn't cheat whenever he doesn't get caught"
>
> I am not sure what the goal was you should've proved or not, so I all named them to the first letter of how you described the statement inside the "" Now lets look at each proposition to see if its just a single proposition or we can break it up into multiple pieces by declaring a distinct letter that means a statement that is true (Whenever we want something to be false we can use a negation)

From reading the four propositions I defined:

> let K be "John gets caught" This can only be true or false.
>
> let L be "John cheats" we reformulated the cheating statement so it can be true or false.
>
> On some places we read the opposite of some statement. Which we can construct using the same statement written in a form such that it reads as being true and then use the negation connective.
>
> In my opinion constructing your propositions in these manners saves yourself from frustration because multiple negations result in a negation or in true whenever you expect the opposite.
>
> But everywhere we read "whenever" which sounds like something connecting statements. But what does the writer mean by whenever. Does the word mean left and right side must both be true, both be equal to each other, one must be true, or if the left is true right may not be false in order to have a proposition that is true.

You said you used whenever in your answers, but was the meaning defined somewhere? If not, did you write down what you assumed it to be? To show why this is important we construct these propositions using the connectives and our own defined statements. I write the "whenever" as ??. We then get

> Q $\equiv$ "K ?? L."
>
> A $\equiv$ "L ?? K"
>
> I $\equiv$ "$\neg(K)$ ?? $\neg(L)
>
> C $\equiv$ $\neg(L) ?? $\neg(K)$

Now try to see results in unexpected behavior using a different connective for all of the propositions, then changing it, see if alle the possible results are equal. For example take an implication, for K is true, and L is false. Then after that Let also L be true... so $K \implies L$ in Q, and also $L \implies K$ in A... so can we replace this with a something else without changing the truth values of the other propositions I and C

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will put some more attention while writing this type of logical proposition.

Comment: I am also not so sure how strict others should be on your description of a definition and your reasoning thing are the way they are. But in the end it should be that the logical reasoning must be correct. That's why we try to make statements abstract so the original context cant bother us in logical reasoning. Good luck!